# как задать размер пустого textarea в списке в строках? (framework7)

Tags: javascript, html, css, framework7

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item-content item-input item-input-outline">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <div class="item-input-wrap">
        <textarea id="word1" class="resizable" placeholder="Word1 word1" rows="4"></textarea>
        <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Выводит поле ввода высотой в 1 строку. Как-то можно, что бы выводил сразу пустое поле ввода высотой в несколько строк?

Comment: Без стилей, что у тебя применяются, не особо понятно как оно у тебя стилизовано...

Answer (score 0):

Размер и прочие параметры textarea регулируются с помощью css/scss/saas

Например

```
textarea {
  width: 94%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```